# multiple email in knockout is not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using Knockout validations for validating fields,
In that for multiple email i am using the below code

```
ko.validation.rules['multiemail'] = {
        validator: function (val, validate) {
            if (!validate) { return true; }

            var isValid = true;
            if (!ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val)) {
                // use the required: true property if you don't want to accept empty values
                var values = val.split(',');
                $(values).each(function (index) {
                    isValid = ko.validation.rules['email'].validator($.trim(this), validate);
                    return isValid; // short circuit each loop if invalid
                });
            }
            return isValid;
        },
        message: 'Please enter valid email addresses (separate multiple email addresses using a comma).'
    };
```

from my viewmodel i am sending as

```
 self.ToEmailAddressList.extend({
            required: { message: "Please enter atleast one email address" },
            multiemail: true
        });
```

But this is not working, can anyone please let me know what i am missing?

Comment: What eaxactly is not working?

Comment: My input box is not taking multiple emails.Validation is getting fired

Comment: its working fine for me check it here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2bq0j6gw/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a call to `ko.validation.registerExtenders();`

More about custom rules [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules)